# Making a fat controller in rails 3 skinny

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this terribly large controller in my app. I'd really like to make it as skinny as possible. Below is some of the code, showing the types of things I'm currently doing.. I'm wondering what things I can move out of this?

A note - this is not my exact code, a lot of it is similar. Essentially every instance variable is used in the views - which is why I dont understand how to put the logic in the models? Can models return the values for instance variables?

```
  def mine

    #For Pusher
    @push_ch = "#{current_user.company.id}"+"#{current_user.id}"+"#{current_user.profile.id}"

    #Creating a limit for how many items to show on the page
    @limit = 10
    if params[:limit].to_i >= 10
      @limit = @limit + params[:limit].to_i     
    end

    #Setting page location
    @ploc="mine"

    @yourTeam = User.where(:company_id => current_user.company.id)
    #Set the user from the param
    if params[:user]
      @selectedUser = @yourTeam.find_by_id(params[:user])
    end

    #Get all of the user tags
    @tags = Tag.where(:user_id => current_user.id)    

    #Load the user's views
    @views = View.where(:user_id => current_user.id)

    if !params[:inbox]

         #Hitting the DB just once for all the posts
         @main_posts = Post.where(:company_id => current_user.company.id).includes(:status).includes(:views)
         @main_posts.group_by(&:status).each do |status, posts|
           if status.id == @status.id
             if @posts_count == nil
               @posts_count = posts
             else
               @posts_count = @posts_count + posts
             end
           elsif status.id == @status_act.id
             if @posts_count == nil
               @posts_count = posts
             else
               @posts_count = @posts_count + posts
             end
           end
         end

         if params[:status] == "All" || params[:status] == nil
           @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).status_filter(params[:status]).user_filter(params[:user]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).where(:company_id => current_user.company.id, :status_id => [@status.id, @status_act.id, @status_def.id, @status_dep.id, @status_up.id]).limit(@limit).includes(:views)
         else
           @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).status_filter(params[:status]).user_filter(params[:user]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).where(:company_id => current_user.company.id).limit(@limit).includes(:views)
         end

    elsif params[:inbox] == "sent"

         @yourcompanylist = User.where(:company_id => current_user.company.id).select(:id).map(&:id)
          @yourcompany = []
          @yourcompanylist.each do |user|
            if user != current_user.id
            @yourcompany=@yourcompany.concat([user])  
            end
          end

          if params[:t]=="all"
            @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).status_filter(params[:status]).user_filter(params[:user]).tag_filter(params[:tag], current_user).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).where(:user_id => current_user.id).includes(:views, :tags).limit(@limit)
          elsif params[:status]!="complete"
            @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).status_filter(params[:status]).user_filter(params[:user]).tag_filter(params[:tag], current_user).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).where(:user_id => current_user.id).includes(:views, :tags).limit(@limit)
          elsif params[:status]!=nil
            @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).status_filter(params[:status]).user_filter(params[:user]).tag_filter(params[:tag], current_user).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).where(:user_id => current_user.id).includes(:views, :tags).limit(@limit)
          end

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
    end
  end
```

Comment: You could use modules and include appropriate methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by moving logic into the model...

A line like this screams of feature envy:

```
@push_ch = "#{current_user.company.id}"+"#{current_user.id}"+"#{current_user.profile.id}"
```

I would recommend moving it into the model:

```
#user.rb
def to_pusher_identity
  "#{self.company_id}#{self.id}#{self.profile_id}"
end
```

And then in your controller

```
@push_ch = current_user.to_pusher_identity
```

At this point you could even move this into a `before_filter`.

```
before_filter :supports_pusher, :only => :mine
```

Another thing you can do is create richer associations, so you can express:

```
@tags = Tag.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

as

```
@tags = current_user.tags
```

Another example would be for main posts, instead of

```
Post.where(:company_id => current_user.company.id).includes(:status).includes(:views)
```

you would go through the associations:

```
current_user.company.posts.includes(:status).includes(:views)
```

Comment: is there a benefit to making the associations like that - or is just the "rails way" so-to-speak?

Comment: That's the rails way, but also it's more concise and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

When I'm drying out a controller/action I try to identify what code could be (should be?) offloaded into the model or even a new module. I don't know enough about your application to really point to where these opportunities might lie, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: In what situation would I decide code should live in a module rather than a controller or model?

Comment: That's a hard call to make. If you've got a body of business logic/behavior that is unrelated to a specific model or perhaps represents something common to a lot of different controller actions that could go into a module. My approach is that the controller should basically be marshalling requests into the various models and back to the views rather than executing a lot of complex business logic.

Comment: Here is a better question - lets say I felt all of the code above should be in the model - how do I move it into it if I need those instance variables to still have values for the view?

Comment: basically you create method(s) on the model that take those variables as parameters. The rule of thumb is that if something is manipulating a model beyond the simple .create(params), update_attributes, save, etc methods it's possible that it is actually model behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Few quick ideas:

Consider using [respond_to/respond_with](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3). This controller action can be splitted up to two separate ones - one for displaying *@main_posts*, another for *params[:inbox] == "sent"*. The duplicate code can be removed using *before_filters*.

Also, a couple of gem suggestions:

- use [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) for pagination
- [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) for search and sorting